# ActiveModel::Serializer Subclass that will accept any attribute dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, active-model-serializers, modularity

I'm building an API engine for an existing app, which will serve JSON with `ActiveModel::Serializer`. On the existing app, There are some controllers that just render regular old hashes that aren't instances of any ActiveModel subclass - originally, these were AJAX endpoints so it didn't matter what class the response body was.

I need to recreate some of these existing endpoints in the API module, so for instances like these, I want to build a custom serializer that will accept whatever attributes you throw at it. something like...

In the Controller:

```
def show
  response = {
    key: "this is a custom object and not an AM instance"
  }
  render json: response, serializer: Api::V1::CustomSerializer
end
```

And the serializer:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CustomSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

      def attributes
        *object.keys.map(&:to_sym)
      end

      def read_attribute_for_serialization(attr)
        object[attr.to_s]
      end


    end
  end
end
```

Couple of problems:

a) The call to render in the controller doesn't seem to like the amount of args I've passed to render, which supposedly takes `*args`, which suggests to me there is something wrong with the override methods I've written.

b) If I were to just put `attributes *object.class.column_names.map(&:to_sym)` in the first line of the class, object is undefined outside of a method.

c) I call it inside a method, the resulting hash is nested inside whatever I choose to call that method. Not really what I had in mind.

My question: has anyone successfully created a serializer that will accept any attribute? Would love to know how.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I would like achieve this with AMS if I can - we're using the adapter for JSON API for all our response bodies. I would much rather make this work then initialize a hash identical to the json api standard we're using every time the response is not an AM instance.

Comment: I have to admit this is an interesting use case are there only few attributes getting build dynamically? or more than that? As a consumer of an API that can return any json dynamically it might be hard for me to deal with deserialization/parsing and might cause errors. I don't know your use case but if possible I would design separate endpoints to support separate use cases

Comment: Ah, good point. I wasn't able to provide a more substantial example variable as I'm still wrapping my mind around the codebase, but point being, it should dynamically map any key in that response variable. There are likely to be many more in our use case, I just wrote a real tiny hash as a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the folks who might have stumbled across the same problem, I ended up assembling a catch-all serializer class for anything i want to render that isn't a subclass of Active Record. Like so:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CustomSerializer

      def initialize(obj, error: false, type: nil)
        @hash = error ? error_hash(obj) : success_hash(type, obj)
      end

      def to_h
        @hash
      end

      private

      def error_hash(obj)
        {
          errors: {
            pointer: obj[:error] || obj[:errors]
          },
          detail: detail(obj)
        }
      end

      def success_hash(type, obj)
        {
          id: obj.try(:id) ? obj[:id] : nil,
          type: type.nil? ? 'hash' : type,
          data: obj.try(:id) ? obj.except(:id) : obj,
          links: ''
        }
      end

      def detail(obj)
        obj[:detail] || obj[:message] || obj[:msg]
      end


    end
  end
end
```

Note that I'm working with the JSON API standard. Then, instead of doing something like this for an activemodel serializer:

```
render json: @device, serializer: Api::V1::DeviceSerializer
```

I can do something like this:

```
render json: Api::V1::CustomSerializer.new(@response, error: false, type: 'feed').to_h
```

basically just means I can still render the JSON api standard for anything that is just an instance of a Hash class, or anything for which I'm doing external API requests and storing in a Hash. Hope this helps someone someday.